# Can Magento support multiple API Integrations?

Tags: magento

I am currently doing some research, and for context I have an API, and I want my API to connect to other Public APIs.

Now, these Public APIs has the ability to connect to Magento. My question is that, Can I use Magento as some sort of a middle man between my API and the Public APIs I want to connect to?

Like if I made a request from my API to Public API 1, can Magento deliver that request to Public API 1? And get the response from Public API 1 to my API?

Any insights is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely you can. I have written extensions that integrated several APIs. For example, processing orders. Check order for validity, hit the vendor api to check stock, hit my own api to check oversize rules or noship rules etc. Then send into a warehouse API to move the order through a status chain. Totally do-able from at least magento 1.6 through 2+ community and enterprise. You can also do it external to magento and hit the magento api depending on your scenario.

Comment: wow thanks! that's somewhat similar to what I was trying to achieve. Thank you for this! I really appreciate it and I now have peace of mind regarding this!!